# Save guid without dashes into SQL Server using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, guid

I'm trying to save a guid in SQL Server, but it is adding dashes and the Guid that comes from the web does not contain

Json receive web, id not contains dash:

```
{
    "id": "000ABAE61B2248C58CC10E170484A994",
    "company": {
        "id": "5661F9785F8049B4BC65E87EED59B8A2",
        "code": 4156,
        "companyname": "GENESLAB DEL PARAGUAY S.A - CONSOLIDADOR",
        "_discriminator": "company"
    },
    "name": "Supervisão Jataí - SEED GO",
    "code": "394",
    "creationDate": "1959-12-31",
    "accountingBranch": 0,
    "_discriminator": "costcenter"
}
```

Before parse, it not contains dashes:

[image: before parse]

After parse

[image: after parse]

How do I keep what comes from the web and save in the bank without the dash?

Comment: After parsing, it's binary. It only has dashes when converted to a string, as the debugger is doing. SQL Server has its own GUID data type called `uniqueidentifier`. You should use that data type (not one of the character data types) so it remains in binary form.

Comment: Sorry it was backwards, I edited the question

Comment: That doesn't change anything. My point stands. The hyphens are not part of the GUID's value, only its representation. Don't save it to the database in string form and the hyphens won't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 options:

1. Don't parse it and treat it as a string.
2. Use `ToString("N")` when you need a version with no dashes.
3. Save it in the database as a Guid (uniqueidentifier in SQL Server), not a string; then the code and the database can use a 'real' guid type, not a string shortcut.